# Problem with calculating VAT

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-ce

I have a cart rule as specified here. It is applied to the shipping when 2 items have been added to the cart

[http://imgur.com/a/1Ulrw](https://imgur.com/a/1Ulrw)

I have a 20% tax rule (United Kingdom) being applied to the product price and the shipping. For the product price it is being deducted correctly, for delivery however it is applying it PRE discount instead of POST discount (so TAX is being applied to £160 shipping instead of £120)

[http://imgur.com/a/zSGth](https://imgur.com/a/zSGth)

Here is my tax rules, I am pretty well stumped to why this is happening

imgur.com/a/DBq4f

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the strategy you want to apply taxex: ***Settings -> Sales ->Tax***. You'll find a select labeled Appy Tax with options: *after discount*, *before discount*.

Comment: the VAT amount remains the same whether it's before discount or after discount. Does this indicate an issue with the price rule itself, or would there be another issue at play here?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your cache configuration?

Comment: I have, still no change

Comment: Can you provide more informations about your current tax settings?

Comment: Here are some screenies

http://imgur.com/a/UzEWZ, 
http://imgur.com/a/U6aKx

Comment: Also http://imgur.com/a/DBq4f, ask if you need anymore information

Comment: Try to change Apply  Discount to Prices to Including Tax. You should see your totals changing, if not there is some caching going on.

Comment: I have managed to get the numbers to crunch correctly by rearranging the price rule. Thanks for your help :)